App is navigating to /api/auth/error instead of /api/auth/sigin in Prod
My app is running fine on my local env but after I deployed it on vercel, I am not able to sign in because it's getting redirected to /api/auth/error and displaying the following message:

"Server error
There is a problem with the server configuration.
Check the server logs for more information."

and the log message is
[GET] /api/auth/error?error=Configuration&nxtPnextauth=error status=500
I did some research online and found that we are required to add NEXTAUTH_SECRET key on production, which I have added now, but the issue still persists.
This is my auth.ts file:
import { DrizzleAdapter } from "@auth/drizzle-adapter";
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { database } from "@/db/database";
import { accounts, sessions, users, verificationTokens } from "@/db/schema";
import { env } from "@/env";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  adapter: DrizzleAdapter(database, {
    usersTable: users,
    accountsTable: accounts as any,
    sessionsTable: sessions,
    verificationTokensTable: verificationTokens,
  }),
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
  },
  providers: [Google],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});

What am I doing wrong?
PS - I'm using NextAuth version 5.0.0-beta.19
Someone mentioned that I should set AUTH_TRUST_HOST="your-prod-url.com",
I have assigning https://auclify.vercel.app/ to it and when that didn't work I also tried assigning true to it(https://authjs.dev/getting-started/deployment#auth_trust_host), but the issue didn't resolve
Update: This is my sample .env file
DATABASE_URL=
AUTH_DRIZZLE_URL=
NODE_ENV=development
AUTH_SECRET=
AUTH_GOOGLE_ID=
AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET=
BUCKET_NAME=
CLOUDFLARE_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
CLOUDFLARE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID=
NEXT_PUBLIC_BUCKET_URL=
NEXT_PUBLIC_KNOCK_PUBLIC_API_KEY=
NEXT_PUBLIC_KNOCK_FEED_ID=

And this is my google console

Also, after adding debugger I am also getting detailed error
[31m[auth][error][0m AdapterError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#adaptererror

[31m[auth][cause][0m: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1606:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)


can you show the google console setup, and can you update the question with the .env configurations

@DileepaMabulage I have added sample .env file keys

You need to add your production URL to the Google console.



I have the same configuration in google console, I have added the screenshot in the question
